# How to use gatsby-background-image and gatsby-remote-image

Tags: gatsby

I  fetch data from google sheets and they field with image URL and I want to display in gatsby as a background image with gatsby image features like lazy loading and responsive image

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-background-image/

Comment: @ksav Thank you for your reply.  I tried gatsby-background-image and gatsby-remote-image but it's didn't work

Comment: @Iliashaddad Show us your code and what happens when you run it.